# All the java process running in my Virtual Machine is dumping threaddump in its logs causing slowness

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

After some upgrade activities in Centos 7 and eclipse Oxygen(4.9.0) , my development Virtual machine has slowed down drastically and noticeably all Java processes in my machine is dumping threads to its logs automatically in approx. 8-10 seconds time period repeatedly.Slowing down the machine and also filling up disk space must faster. Not sure why this is happening.

Doubted Latest JDK1.8.0_201 version, didn't resolve even after changing them to older stable versions

Doubted Centos upgrade but no bugs found in Centos bug history or known issues

Anyone have faced similar issues??

Comment: A SIGQUIT signal will trigger a thread dump.  Look for something that is repeatedly sending SIGQUIT signals to your Eclipse's JVM.

Comment: Have you looked at the log files for clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139985/stephen-c) .you are correct. Using `strace -p <pid>` , i have tested some of the Java processes and found the Culprit process responsible for sending periodical SIGQUIT signal.

`root     32046 31896  1 17:44 pts/3    00:00:22 /opt/jdk1.8.0_201/jre/bin/java -Dloader.path=/opt/jdk1.8.0_201/lib/tools.jar -Dsts.lsp.client=eclipse -Dlsp.completions.indentation.enable=true -Xmx1024m -jar /root/eclipse/java-2018-09/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/571/data/1.2.0.201812201040-spring-boot-language-server-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

After disabling the language-server config in Eclipse and restarting the Eclipse solved the issue .

[image: Eclipse configuration]